# How to get tag's attribute value with namespace?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this example:

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:wor="http://services.tdeu.telekom.net/ServAndResMgmt/TechOrderMgmt/WorkorderProvider_v01.00" 
    xmlns:typ="http://services.tdeu.telekom.net/ServAndResMgmt/TechOrderMgmt/WorkorderProvider_v01.00/types"
    xmlns:csdg="http://schemas.telekom.net/csdg_v01.01" 
    xmlns:typ1="http://system-services.t-home.telekom.de/ServiceManagement/TechnicalOrderManagement/Workorder_v01.00/types" 
    xmlns:com="http://system-services.t-home.telekom.de/ServiceManagement/OIS_Services_v01.00/common">
<!-- other tags -->
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How to get values of "soapenv:Envelope" tag's attributes by xpath?
I tried `//*:Envelope/@*[local-name()='xmlns:soapenv']` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, those declarations are not attributes but namespaces nodes. To get them with XPath, it depends of what version of XPath you use.

For XPath 1, use :

```
/*/namespace::*
```

For XPath 2, use : `fn:in-scope-prefixes` and `fn:namespace-uri-for-prefix` to get the prefix and the associated namespace uri.